# Cassandra "Unexpected error deserializing mutation" error

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Cassandra stopped.
when i restart Cassandra using "service cassandra start" or "service cassandra restart", i get the following error(from "/var/log/cassandra/system.log"):

```
ERROR [main] 2014-11-14 02:08:52,379 CommitLogReplayer.java (line 304) Unexpected error deserializing mutation; saved to /tmp/mutation3145492124947244713dat and ignored.  This may be caused by replaying a mutation against a table with the same name but incompatible schema.  Exception follows:
org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MarshalException: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (7)
        at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.TimestampSerializer.validate(TimestampSerializer.java:118)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.validate(AbstractType.java:171)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.validateCollectionMember(AbstractType.java:289)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractCompositeType.validate(AbstractCompositeType.java:282)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:274)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:95)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:151)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:131)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:336)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:496)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:585)
```

now i cannot start cassandra.
cqlsh is also not available.

Answer (score 5):

I also encounter this problem. I'd like to share how I resolve the problem.

- Change the debug mode

  The default debug mode is INFO, the output is too less to track the error. You should change the debug mode from INFO to DEBUG. This is  is determined by the following line in the log4j-server.properties file:

  > log4j.rootLogger=INFO,stdout,R
- rerun the cassandra

  From the output, I find the error appears when replay the commit log file. I think there are something wrong in the log file. But the log file is binary, I don't know how to read it. So I try to delete the log file that results in the error, then restart cassandra. And it works!

Maybe the root problem is different from mine, but you can try to find it in this way. Hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you! :D
we'll try this.